# How To Deserialize a JSON Object Polymorphicly?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize data from an API in JSON format. There are four different queries I am making to get data. They are as follows: GetDatasetlist, GetParameterList, GetParameterValues, and GetData. Each query returns a JSON formatted string with a similar format. The format is below:

```
API : {

        Request :
        {
              RequestParam :
               [{...}, {...}, {...}]
        },

        Results :
        {
            [Dataset],[Parameter],[ParamValue],[Data]
        }
}
```

The variable part of the JSON string is under results where I will get one of either Dataset, Parameter, ParamValue, or Data, depending on the query I am executing. While I could handle each case entirely independently and work around the problem, that seems like the incorrect decision, given that so much of the code overlaps.

All four potential return objects are structurally different than the other, but I was wondering if there was still a way to handle them using polymorphism.

The classes I created to deserialize the JSON code are below:

```
        public class QueryResults
        {
            public _API API { get; set; }
            public List<_RequestParam> RequestParams { get { return API.Request.RequestParam; } }
        }
        public class _API
        {
            public _Request Request { get; set; }
            public _Results Results { get; set; }

        }
        public class _Request
        {
            public List<_RequestParam> RequestParam { get; set; }
        }
        public class _RequestParam
        {
            public string ParameterName { get; set; }
            public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
        }
        public class _Results
        {
             ???
        }
```

I already tried using nullable types, but I am using C# 7.3, which does not allow for that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could just have your `API` class be generic, with the generic part being the type of the `Results` property. Then, all you'd need to do is provide the right generic type for the requested API.

Comment: How would you differentiate between the different object types?

Comment: you need to read about discriminated unions OneOf<....>, i found detailed example for you: https://code-maze.com/csharp-discriminated-unions-with-oneof/